# Run aggregrate query in mongocxx as a string literal

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

In the mongocxx API, [Collection.aggregate()](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/api/mongocxx-v3/classmongocxx_1_1collection.html#aa93a46c9e07878fbddeb3ca29af71fc4) expects a pipeline object in order to run an [aggregate pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/#aggregation-pipeline) query. This means constructing the query by using the Pipeline class. Such as:

```
    mongocxx::pipeline p{};
    p.match(make_document(kvp("items.fruit", "banana")));
    p.sort(make_document(kvp("date", 1)));
    auto cursor = db["sales"].aggregate(p, mongocxx::options::aggregate{});
```

Is there a way to run an aggregate pipeline query in mongocxx by passing in a string? I'm not looking to construct the query using a mongocxx object, but running the query as a string.

For example:

```
    db["sales"].aggregate("[{"$match": {  ... }}"]
```

where "[{"$match": {  ... }}" is a pipeline aggregate query of type std::string.

Comment: You can parse a string into a bson document instead of building one up, is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking to have the entire query as a string which I can run using mongocxx.

Comment: Not the entire string, but the pipeline components (match, sort, etc.) you can parse as JSON fragments using `bsoncxx::from_json`.

Comment: No, there is not currently a way to construct such a thing. However it may be very easy to add. Would you mind filing a ticket? https://jira.mongodb.org/projects/CXX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use run_command of [mongocxx::database](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/api/mongocxx-v3/classmongocxx_1_1database.html)

```
bsoncxx::builder::basic::document command_document{};

command_document.append(kvp(
"eval",
"function(username) {"
"return db.users.findOne( { username : username } );"
"}"));

command_document.append(kvp("args", [&](sub_array child) {
child.append(username);
}));

auto doc = db.run_command({command_document});
```

This is a simple example of using string function with arguments to run on Mongodb by mongocxx now you can use it for any command that you want.
Is this that you need ?